# Is there a way to check the life of a token?

Tags: linux, bash, openstack, openstack-keystone

I need to check if the token is valid every time I run the script. In case it is valid, but skip the procedure for generating a new token.
Is it possible to implement this by means of api?

I receive a token through curl

```
export SYS_TOKEN=curl --silent -i --cacert "$OS_CACERT" \
        -X POST $OS_AUTH_URL/v3/auth/tokens -d '{"auth":{"identity":\
        {"methods":["password"],"password":{"user":{"name": "'$USERNAME'", "domain":\
        {"name": "default"}, "password": "'$PASSWORD'"}}}}}' \
        -H 'Content-type: application/json' | \
        awk -F ':' '/^X-Subject-Token/ {print $2}' | sed -e 's/\r$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Keystone implements the [Check Token API](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=check-token-detail#check-token).

I do wonder what is the use case. Whenever you submit an API, the token's validity is checked anyway. What do you gain by checking validity yourself?

Comment: I have a script that asks for a new token every time it starts. I would like to make a validation check so that there are no such frequent requests.